# How to get the value of specific array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, woocommerce

I have this code in woocommerce using php. I do print_r($meta[1]) and it has output below

```
WC_Meta_Data Object ( [current_data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 455885 [key] => _end_date_custom_field [value] => 2023-01-18 ) [data:protected] => Array ( [id] => 455885 [key] => _end_date_custom_field [value] => 2023-01-18 ) )
```

How can get the value of [value] key? I tried different combinations but not working

i tried echo($meta[1][value]); but it is not working what did i do wrong?

Comment: Probably using the `get_data` method on your [object instance](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Meta-Data.html).

Comment: Looking at the [WooCommerce docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Meta-Data.html), the `WC_Meta_Data` class has implemented the `__get` magic method and has the comment `Returns the value of any property.`, so I would assume you could do `$meta[1]->value`

Comment: @RJK Thank you very much! It works!

Comment: @EasyWay I have posted an answer, if it has helped you can you please accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [WooCommerce docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Meta-Data.html#method___get), the `WC_Meta_Data` class has implemented the `__get` [magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) and has the comment `Returns the value of any property.`, so I would assume you could do :

`$meta[1]->value`

Cheers